# Excel Vba Need A Stop

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all i made this vba program and an what it does is go's through each sheet and delete some cells and word's well I made it up to sheet 7 I need a way to stop it from running Say if there is only 5 sheets I want it to stop at 5 and not try to run the other two because it errors out.

I am Very very new at this can you also take a look at this and see if you are able to shorten it and or make it run better.

```
Sub Step1()


' 9/20/2013
' Made by Douglas Covey




    Sheets("1D_report").Select
    Rows("3:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("E1:F2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearContents

   '
   ' Search and Delete.
   '

    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    s = "Utilization, %"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(8, 0)).Clear

        Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Clear

        s = "Total Cost:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Clear

    Sheets("1D_report").Name = "Comingsoon_report"


    '
    ' Sheet Number Two
    '


   Sheets("1D_1").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    '
    ' Sheet Number Tree
    '


      Sheets("1D_2").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False



    '
    ' Sheet Number Four
    '


        Sheets("1D_3").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False




    '
    ' Sheet Number Five
    '



        Sheets("1D_4").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False



    '
    ' Sheet Number Six
    '



            Sheets("1D_5").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False





    '
    ' Sheet Number Seven
    '




            Sheets("1D_6").Select


    Rows("4:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               s = "Qty:"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp


      Range("E8").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: What I need is a way to stop it if there is No more sheets left

Comment: David Zemens Can you help?

Comment: See my answer below. It is untested because I'm not going to try and replicate your workbook, but it should give you a good idea of how to make your code more efficient.

Comment: I am curious how you thought to ask for me by name, though :)

Comment: Went to your profile and saw you knew vba with excel =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some general advice:  Stop relying on `Selection`.  Look at this code (yours):

```
Sheets("1D_report").Select
Rows("3:9").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("E1:F2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.ClearContents   "<-- This line is redundant
```

This is how the macro recorder gives you code -- **and it's how almost everyone starts with VBA in Excel** so there's no shame in it.  But the recorder is very literal, recording every keystroke, selection, activation, etc.  It is useful for *seeing* what happens, but can almost always be consolidated.  Consolidating the code makes it more human-readable, it will execute faster, and be easier to maintain.

Compare that to this code:

```
With Sheets("1D_report")
    .Rows("3:9").Delete Shift:=xlUP
    .Range("E1:F2").ClearContents
    .Range("H:H").ClearContents
End With
```

Instead of writing a macro that mimics point-and-click, I modify that to work *directly* on the objects (worksheets, cells, ranges/ etc).

Now, let's also take only what you did with `1D_Report` worksheet, and show you how to use subroutines/functions.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    If Not SearchAndClear(Worksheets("1D_report"), "Utilization, %", 8, 0) Then Exit Sub
    If Not SearchAndClear(Worksheets("1D_report"), "Utilization, %", 0, 1) Then Exit Sub
    If Not SearchAndClear(Worksheets("1D_report"), "Total Cost:", 0, 1) Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**The above code relies on a function to perform repeatable operations**.  Here is the function:

```
Function SearchAndClear(ws As Worksheet, srchString As String, rOff As Long, cOff As Long) As Boolean
    With ws
        Set r = .Cells.Find(srchString, .Range("A1"))
        If r Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
            SearchAndClear = False
        End If
        .Range(r, r.Offset(rOff, cOff)).Clear
        SearchAndClear = True
    End With
End Function
```

**Putting it all together...**

This is untested, but should I think do everything that you were doing. It's a lot less code, and a lot easier to read through and debug if you have trouble, or need to modify things.

It's valuable to create functions/subroutines for *repeatable* code, that way you don't need to repeat it, you simply call on the function/sub multiple times.  It's only one thing that you need to fix or revise in the future, instead of many things to update, if you ever need to change the code.

Using the `Select Case` statement allows you to do particular operations based on the case value, in this case we're checking the worksheet's name.  It will *never* act on worksheets that don't exist :)

```
Sub Test()
        Dim r As Range
        Dim s As String
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "1D_report"
                    With ws
                        .Rows("3:9").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        .Range("E1:F2").ClearContents
                        .Range("H:H").ClearContents
                    End With
                    If Not SearchAndClear(ws, "Utilization, %", 8, 0) Then Exit Sub
                    If Not SearchAndClear(ws, "Utilization, %", 0, 1) Then Exit Sub
                    If Not SearchAndClear(ws, "Total Cost:", 0, 1) Then Exit Sub
                    ws.Name = "Comingsoon_report"

                Case "1D_1", "1D_2", "1D_3", "1D_4", "1D_5", "1D_6"  '<-- You do the same operations on ALL of these sheets!
                    With ws
                        .Rows("4:9").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End With
                    If Not SearchAndClear(ws, "Qty:", 0, 1) Then Exit Sub

                    Set r = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Page", After:=ws.Range("E8"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                        False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    r.Replace What:="Page", Replacement:="Program", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

                Case Else
                'You could add additional logic for other worksheets, if needed
                '
                '

            End Select
        Next                
    End Sub
    Function SearchAndClear(ws As Worksheet, srchString As String, rOff As Long, cOff As Long) As Boolean
    With ws
        Set r = .Cells.Find(srchString, .Range("A1"))
        If r Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
            SearchAndClear = False
        End If
        .Range(r, r.Offset(rOff, cOff)).Clear
        SearchAndClear = True
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: David I need to talk to you

Comment: @pnuts thanks you're absolutely correct this code was untested I will revise

Comment: I also omitted the `Next` statement corresponding to the `For each ws` :) which is now also revised :)